# Sending mail php

Tags: php, email

Hey, no idea why this sint working, but the message is being sent as "0". I think the e-mail fIELD is what is causing it

```
    <?php
if ($_POST['check'] == 'checked'){
        header("location: /nospamplease.html");
        exit();
}

$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$date = $_POST['date'];
$children = $_POST['children'];
$hot = $_POST['hot'];
$comments = $_POST['comments'];

/*echo $name;
echo $email;
echo $phone;
echo $date;
echo $children;
echo $hot;
echo $comments;*/

if($name == "" || $email == "" || $phone == "" || $date == "" || $children == "" || $hot == "" || $comments == ""){
    echo "Please ensure all fields were filled out!";
    exit();
}else{
    $to = "######";
    $subject = "Birthday enquiry";
    $message = "Name: ".$name;
    $message += "Email: ".$email;
    $message += "Phone: ".$phone;
    $message += "Date: ".$date;
    $message += "Children: ".$children;
    $message += "Hot or cold: ".$hot;
    $message += "Comments: ".$comments;
    //echo $message;
    if(mail($to, $subject, $message)){
        echo "Thank you for your enquiry, we will contact you within the next 24 hours! <br /> Click <a href='###'> here</a> to go back to the website!";
    }else{
        echo "There was an error, contact us directly: <a href='mailto:##'>email</a>";
    }
}
?>
```

I echoed out the variables, they all are getting posted fine

Thanks guys

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't use `+` to concatenate strings in PHP. Use `.`

```
$message .= "Email: ".$email;
```

Comment: Aha of course, been working with too much java this month :S cheers bud